# Enabling Internet Connection Through Proxy in Android in Windows

Tags: android, windows

How to Enable Internet Connection Through Proxy in Android in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/462906/Android/Mobile/connect-internet-behind-proxy

In the earlier versions of Android emulators (up to version 1.1r2), you were required to make an entry in the system table of“com.android.provider.setting.db” database and/or start the emulator with –http-proxy switch supplying it the IP address and port number of your proxy.

These methods however, have become obsolete and don’t work with SDKv1.5.
Step 1: On emulator, go to:
Home->Menu->Settings->WirelessControls->MobileNetworks->Access Point Names->T-mobile US->set Proxy IP and Port#

Step 2: Now the next time you go to a web address, the browser will prompt for your user-id and password. Enter your credentials and you should be good to go.

Reference: http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/b…d4f948c4ed622#5ced4f948c4ed622” target=”_new” rel=”nofollow”>

Steps for Android 2.2

1) Create an emulator with name say android_2.2_emulator using AVD manager in eclipse.

2) Create a batch file (.bat) with following command and a keep a handy shortcut.

emulator -avd “android_2.2_emulator” -http-proxy “your_proxy_url”:”port”

3) Run the batch file before starting the eclipse IDE, so that the emulator session will have internet connection.

That’s it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your Android device a static IP. Ensure both the Windows computer and the Android device are on the same subnet. Set the IP of the android device as the gateway for the Lan connection on the Windows computer.