# Where can I get detailled Informations about AVD?

Tags: java, android, proxy

I work on an android app (3.0) which gets informations from a local webservice (with a private IP adress). I am able to get these informations from a browser (on the host side) but not from the ADV generated by Eclipse.

I think that these problems are due to the proxy of the company.

That's why I would like to know exactly how AVD works when generated on my machine ?
How does it connect to the web ?
On which networks is it been created ?
What is its IP adress ? Rights ?

Do you know where I can get the kind on information please ?
The Android documentation doesn't help me on this point, or maybe it is not the good one

Thanks a lot

[fr]

Comment: Is it ADV or AVD?  BTW - it is probably best to ask one question per ..question.  As opposed to **5**.  Also, please leave out noise like 'thanks' & sigs.

Comment: It's AVD* - All my questions are intended to get at least one answer that certainly point me in the right direction to solve my problem - This is certainly my first publication, it doesn't mean that I'm new to the site and I dont know rules of conduct ;) Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all your questions can be solved in the [Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) document.

Comment: This link is very usefull, thank's. I also use [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731643/enabling-internet-connection-through-proxy-in-android-in-windows)